# Magento 1.9.1.0 deducts VAT/TAX from order total in shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, vat

I have a problem where magento keeps deducting the tax from the order total.
Can't figure out why it's doing that.
As you can see in below picture. The order total should be €5,20. But the €0,90 is being deducted instead.

[image]

Here's my tax rule, vat is set to 21%:

[image]

Here are my settings in the backend:

[image]

Does anyone know where I should look to fix this? Thanks

As for clarification:

[image]

As you can see. The total should be €7,20. But the VAT/TAX of €1.25 is deducted instead. Totalling: €5,95.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've figured out what was wrong.

We were using ET Payment Extra Charge extension.
I thought disabling it from the backend would show me if this would be the culprit.

But I had to completely remove it.

Now the tax calculation is correct agian. So check your extensions!

Everybody thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

please check if the flag "Include Tax in Grand Total" is set to Yes,

This settings in sistem->configuration->Tax->Shopping Cart Display Settings"

In mine default installation is set to "No" 
[image]

Giuseppe

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Sorry to say that it doesn't work.

Comment: That will only 'show' extra tax information. It doesn't solve the problem, that magento is deducting the vat instead off adding it.

Comment: Please try to show both price for the total including and ecxluding tax. This will help you to verify if it is a calculation error or just a visualization one.

Comment: I've enabled all displaying options from the backend. Added the screenshot to my question. But as you can see. The VAT is still being deducted. It's plain weird.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging Magento 101: TURN OFF ALL YOUR CRAPPY MODULES !! And flush your cache by removing all files in var/cache or with Redis command "flushall". Or go to the beckend and do it there and wait a while..... :-(

You have to do this in app/etc/modules/xxxxxx.XML
If you `disable` it in the `backend`. Your only disable output of blocks.

Just look at: Mage_Core_Block_Abstract..... toHtml() !

Answer (score -1):

Check if Mage_Tax is enabled (System->Configuration->Advanced)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, you should place a comment to ask if they have done this

Comment: Yes it is enabled. Otherwise tax wouldn´t function at all.